# DrawLine with SolidBrush is not really solid color

Tags: c#, graphics

Here is my code to draw a line with a SolidBursh:

```
Brush aGradientBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
gdPrintImage.DrawLine(new Pen(aGradientBrush), 20, 20, 20, 100);
```

But it seem the line is not really solid color, check the picture:

[image]

The color like the gradient.

Comment: At this magnification factor you are looking at the molecules in the ink.  Compare to Graphics.InterpolationMode, this is what happens when the bitmap is interpolated.

Comment: Many thanks, I'll check again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line is solid, and is 1 pixels wide.
You are viewing the resulting image at 3000% magnification in what I assume is an image viewer which applies image interpolation when zooming.
View the resulting image in a non-interpolating image viewer and you will see it is solid.